# UIPageViewController: automatic scroll to a certain page

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uipageviewcontroller

**How do I scroll to a certain page on a UIPageViewController?**

I have a UIPageViewController which works perfectly but then I have a UICollectionView that has all the pages from the UIPageviewController. What I want to do is when a user taps at a certain page, I navigate back to my UIPageViewController and display the page that was tapped.

This is how I did it:

1. get the indexpath.item of the tapped page = page number
2. perform segue and send the page number to the UIPageViewController,
3. Goes into my `reloadPageviewController` method where it grabs the view controller in the `viewControllers` array and use `setViewControllers:@[vc] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil` to set the View controller and then add child controller(actual content view controller) and add subview.

**I log the index of the view controller and it logs the desired index(the page that was tapped) but on the screen you see the first page.**

Here is my code:

Segue from CollectionView to UIPageViewController

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"specificLocation"]) {
    //index here is good
    NSLog(@"index for vc clicked:%d", chosenIndexPath.item);
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(prepareData:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:chosenIndexPath.item] waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

UIPageViewController

```
-(void)prepareData:(NSNumber *) index{

   NSInteger index2 = [index integerValue];
  //Correct index received here
   NSLog(@"Receieved index:%d", index2);
   [self reloadPageViewControllerWithIndex:index2];
}

 -(void)reloadPageViewControllerWithIndex:(NSInteger)index{


    //SET UP THE first PAGE
    j=0;
    self.viewcontrollers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {

       ViewController *vc = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
       vc.index = i;

       vc.title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page :%d", i];

       [self.viewcontrollers addObject:vc];
    }


    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    NSLog(@"Index for requested vc:%d and total number of vcs:%d",index,    [self.viewcontrollers count]);
    ViewController *vc2 = [self viewControllerForIndex:index];
    NSArray *viewControllers = @[vc2];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

So my problem is even though i have the correct index of the view controller I want to display, my UIPageViewController always ends up displaying the first view controller in the self.viewcontrollers array

Comment: What do you want exactly ? (what is the question) It's not clear for me.

Comment: Suggested an edit for clarifications. Took me 2 minutes as well, to find what the problem was.

Comment: Added a conclusion summarising my problem